# Does python insert function have something like BACKWARD INHERITANCE?

Tags: python, arrays, list, insert

Hey people of the internet,
help me out on this one, does python insert function `list.insert(index,element)` have something like backward inheritance?, If there is something like that.
If not, then why is is n being edited when I insert something in n1 even when.

[image]

Comment: because `n1` is a reference to `n`, not a copy of it

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)